# Github Action failing to run pytest due to ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, continuous-integration, pytest, github-actions, python-poetry

I have a python project structure using poetry as package manager and pytest to run tests. The project has a structure like:

```
.github/
  workflows/
    test_workflow.yml
src/
  __init__.py
  exceptions.py
tests/
  test_utils.py
pyproject.toml
poetry.lock
```

Now, inside `test_utils.py` there are tests that import some exceptions from `exceptions.py`:

```
from src.exceptions import DateNotFoundError, ParameterNotFoundError
```

This is all fine, running `poetry run pytest` inside a `venv` in my local environment works correctly and the test are passing.

Now I'm trying to set up a GitHub action to run the tests on each commit. What I have is this:

```
name: test
run-name: Run unit tests
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3.11.4'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install poetry==1.6.1
        poetry install
    - name: Run tests
      run: poetry run pytest
```

Which throws the following error in github actions: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

This is the complete stacktrace:

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_utils.py __________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/runner/work/MyProject/MyProject/tests/test_utils.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/myproject-n2wF6nQj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:617: in _importtestmodule
    mod = import_path(self.path, mode=importmode, root=self.config.rootpath)
../../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/myproject-n2wF6nQj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/pathlib.py:567: in import_path
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1204: in _gcd_import
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1176: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1147: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:690: in _load_unlocked
    ???
../../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/myproject-n2wF6nQj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:186: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
tests/test_utils.py:3: in <module>
    from src.exceptions import DateNotFoundError, ParameterNotFoundError
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR tests/test_utils.py
=============================== 1 error in 1.42s ===============================
make: *** [Makefile:18: test] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

I already tried different Github actions to install poetry, enabling virtual environments through the yaml file and adding `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$PWD"` to the workflow but all yield the exact same result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed by adding a `__init__.py` file to the `tests/` directory.